# DB request with a list in where clause in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to have a where clause with a previous list ?

For exemple :

```
List<Stable> StableList= db.Stables.Where(s => s.OwnerId == user.UserId).ToList();

List<Pony> PonyList= db.Ponys.Where(p=> p.PonyStableId == {StableList.StableId })OrderByDescending(p => p.PostDate).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<int> StableList= db.Stables.Where(s => s.OwnerId == user.UserId)
                             .Select(s => s.StableId)
                             .ToList();


List<Pony> PonyList= db.Ponys.Where(p=> StableList.Contains(p.PonyStableId))
                             .OrderByDescending(p => p.PostDate)
                             .ToList();
```

Probably not the most efficient.  You could do a `Join` between `Stables` and `Ponys` where `Stable.OwnderId == User.UserId`.  That would work too.

Comment: Yep thx it's work ! Still ore efficient that a double foreach ;)

Comment: Remember to mark the question as answered by clicking on the tick next to the answer

Comment: @Camille: yep don forget "Mark As Answer" bro

Comment: @Hosein: upvote for being cool, and a nerd at the same time ;)  The nerd part by the way is checking out SO on a sunday.....

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt: lol, No offense taken, but here in my country Sunday is a working day:D